# Issue with async function

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, google-calendar-api

The function below is a slightly adapted version of the Google Calendar API quickstart sample in javascript. 
I've changed it so that it will loop through the code so that it gets the events from all calendars within the account. The problem I'm having is, regardless of using callbacks or promises, the array returns empty unless I delay a console.log by a couple seconds so that the function finishes it's task. 
I've tried to follow various examples of applying promises and callbacks but I must be missing something as they don't seem to work as expected.

Sorry If it's something silly I'm missing!

```
      function listUpcomingEvents() {

        dateEnd.setDate(dateEnd.getDate() + 6); // load from now till 6 days from now worth of events 
        var eventArray = [];

        for (i1 = 0; i1 < calendarIDs.length; i1++) { 

            gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
            'calendarId': calendarIDs[i1].ID,
            'timeMin': date.toISOString(),
            'showDeleted': false,
            'singleEvents': true,
            'timeMax': dateEnd.toISOString(),
            'orderBy': 'startTime'
                }).then(function(response) {
                  var events = response.result.items;


              if (events.length > 0) {
                for (i2 = 0; i2 < events.length; i2++) {
                  var event = events[i2];
                  var when = event.start.dateTime;
                  if (!when) {
                    when = event.start.date;
                  }
                  var eventObject = {User:event.organizer.displayName, Location:event.location,Summary: event.summary,Date: when};
                  eventArray.push(eventObject);

                  appendPre(event.organizer.displayName + event.location + event.summary + ' (' + when + ')');


                } //for loop events within a calendar 
              } //if statement
            }); //promise
        } //for loop for calendars
        return eventArray;
    } //function end
```

Comment: You're looking for `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the quick reply. I don't suppose you could elaborate on how the promises should be implemented?

Comment: https://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-10/advanced-promise-usage/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks